# Django date format issue - does not match format

Tags: python, django

I need to change the date into the format `MM/YY`. The issue is I don't always don't what the date format is to begin with. It's my understanding that the code below would need to know what format the date was in first before I can change it is that correct?

```
newdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(mydate), '%Y/%m/%d').strftime('%m-%Y')
```

as a result I get the error:

> time data '2020-09-30' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d' (

How to I convert my date to MM/YY?

I'm using Django 1.4.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
newdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(mydate), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%Y')
```